# Ruby Builder Gem - dynamically set node name

Tags: ruby, builder

I'm currently using the Builder gem for Ruby to generate XML representations for resources in my application. The XML representation has multiple child nodes that are always structure the same, but the top-level node has a different name, depending on the value of a boolean property of the resource. Is there any way I can generate builder nodes dynamically? Something like this (tried this already, doesn't work):

```
if resource.attr
  top_level_node = :ForFlowBased
else
  top_level_node = :ForNonSeamlessOffload
end

builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
builder.send(top_level_node). do |top_level_node|
....
end
```

That code will generate a node `<send:ForFlowBased>`. Similarly if I call `builder.(top_level_node)`, the xml generated is `<call:ForFlowBased>`. I'm looking to dynamically send builder the method I want to invoke on it, without adding send or call to the XML as well.

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
builder.tag!(top_level_node) do |top_level_node|

end
```